# To get selected row id

Tags: javascript, .net

I done coding in .net MVC..I am facing issues I have one table when I select particular row then click on set button my model popup window needs to open what I enter it needs to save in database.

```
<button class="btn btn-success" id="btnOpenPopup" onclick="openSetConfirmedModal()">Set Confirmed QPL</button>
```

`                 @foreach (var item in Model.BUDGET_QPL_GENERATOR_List)

```
                    {

                        <tr>

                        <td>

                           

                                <span style="display:none" >@item.ID</span>

                            @* id="checkboxItem" *@

                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxItem" data-rowid="@item.ID" onchange="colorDatatableRow(this)" />

                            </td>

                            <td data-search="@item.QPL_NAME">

                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QPL_NAME)

                            </td>

                            <td data-search="@item.QPL_TYPE">

                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QPL_TYPE)

                            </td>`
```

Comment: Please check your code - your `foreach` doesn't seem to have its closing curly brace, and your `tr` element is missing its closing tag.